# Is there a way with ZXing.net to get an integer or boolean array?

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing.net

I want to generate QR-Codes (or DM-Codes) in my CAM-software. For this task I don't need a bitmap rather coordinates like a kind of 2D integer array.

An example of what I mean:

[image: An example of what I mean]

I tried ZXing.net but I only could create bitmaps. Is there a way with ZXing.net to get an integer or boolean array? Or does an other library exist, which can encode like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to get a BitMatrix or a 2D int array instead of a bitmap.
In my opinion the second one is the best. But it depends on your needs.

```
    // first way to get a BitMatrix instead of a bitmap
    var writer1 = new ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeWriter();
    var bitmatrix = writer1.encode(
        "<content>",
        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        1,
        1,
        new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>());

    // second way to get a BitMatrix instead of a bitmap
    var writer2 = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter<BitMatrix>
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Renderer = new BitMatrixRenderer()
    };
    var bitmatrix2 = writer2.Write("content");

    // third way to get a 2D int array instead of a bitmap
    var writer3 = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter<int[,]>
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Renderer = new BitArray2DRenderer()
    };
    var bitarray2D = writer3.Write("content");

    public class BitMatrixRenderer : IBarcodeRenderer<BitMatrix>
    {
        public BitMatrix Render(BitMatrix matrix, BarcodeFormat format, string content)
        {
            return matrix;
        }

        public BitMatrix Render(BitMatrix matrix, BarcodeFormat format, string content, EncodingOptions options)
        {
            return matrix;
        }
    }

    public class BitArray2DRenderer : IBarcodeRenderer<int[,]>
    {
        public int[,] Render(BitMatrix matrix, BarcodeFormat format, string content)
        {
            return Render(matrix, format, content, null);
        }

        public int[,] Render(BitMatrix matrix, BarcodeFormat format, string content, EncodingOptions options)
        {
            var result = new int[matrix.Width, matrix.Height];
            for (var y = 0; y < matrix.Height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < matrix.Width; x++)
                {
                    result[x, y] = matrix[x, y] ? 1 : 0;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```